# Removing PHP Lines from an HTML File Using Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, syntax

I have been asked to remove PHP from html files.  I believe that I can automate this process with Python, but I'm stuck on multi-line, PHP code.  Below is an example of the PHP code.

```
<?php 
  $seg = $this->uri->segment(2);
  $active_2 = '';$active_1 = '';$active_4 = ''; $active_3 = '';
  if($seg == "Enrichment"){
      $active_1 = 'class="active"';
  }
  elseif($seg == "Nightlife"){
     $active_2 = 'class="active"'; 
  }
  elseif($seg == "Misc"){
     $active_3 = 'class="active"'; 
  }
  else $active_4 = 'class="active"';
?>
<a class="" href="<?php echo base_url()?>"><div class="logo">Page Name</div></a>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>category/all" <?php echo $active_4?> onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','categories','All'])">All</a>
```

Here is my code.  As you can see, I am not handling multi-line occurrences.  I have managed to extract every other PHP occurrence all by myself, tho, so I've got that going for me.

```
with open('C:/Users/B/Documents/Python(s)/aaa_phpshit/top_header.php', 'r') as php_file:
for line in php_file:
    while line.find("<?php") > 0: 
        if "<?php" in line.lower() and "?>" in line:
            line = line.replace(line[line.find("<?php"):line.find("?>")+len("?>")].strip(), "")
        else:
            break
    print line
```

I've tried several different things to solve the multi-line, but nothing's worked yet.  Any recommendations or insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you keep start pos of "<?php" in a list/dict, and continue parsing the string till "?>" (no matter what line) ? Like a record: {Xnth:{'start':posx,'end':posz}}

Comment: regex replace `<\?php.*?\?>`

Comment: @hjpotter92 I was hoping to use pure python because (a) I want to learn and (b) I really suck at regex (there are always corner cases which I don't catch b/c regex doesn't mind) -- even more so than I do at python.  additionally, even with regex, multi-line occurrences still require that I forgo looping line-by-line, right?  I would need simply to var_name = open(doc).read()??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Best way is to use [RE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)***

---

***Example:***

```
import re

with open('php_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    html = re.sub('<\?.*?\?>', '', f.read(), re.MULTILINE)

with open('html_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient example, but to give you an start :

```
k = 0
x = 0
ln = len(html)
ret = ''
while True:
    if html[x:x + 5] == '<?php':
        ret = '%s%s' % (ret, html[k:x])
        k = x
        x += 4
    if html[x:x + 2] == '?>':
        k = x + 2

    x += 1
    if x >= ln:
        ret = '%s%s' % (ret, html[k:])
        break

print(ret)
```

Obviously, your source is in html var. Note that is no check for errors: if you forget to close the php tag, the result is as wrong as your html/php source

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do it line by line. And regex are really worth studying :)

```
import re

php_file = open(filename, 'r').read()
html = re.sub('<\?.*?\?>', '', php_file, re.MULTILINE)
```

please mind that [lazy syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) (i.e. non-greedy) in regexp

Answer (score 0):

Here's the exact code I used to complete my task.  Thank you to the SO users for their help.  Hopefully this question/code helps someone else someday.

```
import os
import re
dir_list = ['views/templates','views/pages']
for dir in dir_list:
for file in os.listdir('C:/Users/B/Documents/Python(s)/application/'+dir):
    if file.endswith(".php"):
        with open('C:/Users/B/Documents/Python(s)/application/'+dir+'/' + file, 'r') as f:
            html = f.read()
            php_compile = re.compile("<\?.*?\?>", re.DOTALL)
            html = re.sub(php_compile, '', html)
        with open('C:/Users/B/Documents/Python(s)/application/'+dir+'/' + file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(html)
    else:
        print "dir name: ", dir
        print "\nfile name: ", file, "\n"
```